# Onclick with two functions- React

Tags: reactjs

How can I call two functions via onclick? 
I have the following code, and with each click the status is updated. I wish, however, that the timer method was also called.

```js
<Button className="btn-link" color="primary" size="lg" style={{ position: "absolute", left: 250 }} onClick={() => this.setState({ index: 1, visibility: true })}>160x600</Button>
```

the timer method:

```js
timer() {
    if (this.timeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    }

    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ visibility: false });
    }, 7000);
  }
```

this is the complete component code.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';

class PubblicitaPulsanti extends Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    iframeSrcs: ["/300x250", "/160x600", "/468x60", "/728x90"],
    heightSrcs: [250, 600, 60, 90],
    widthSrcs: [300, 160, 468, 728],
    visibility: false,
    leftSrcs: [1230, 50, 500, 400],
    rightSrcs: [0, 0, 20, 20],
    topSrcs: [10, 10, 500, 500]
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.onKeyDown.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.onKeyDown.bind(this));
  }


  onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 17) {
      this.reload();
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 96) {
      this.setState({ index: 0, visibility: true });
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 97) {
      this.setState({ index: 1, visibility: true });
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 98) {
      this.setState({ index: 2, visibility: true });
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 99) {
      this.setState({ index: 3, visibility: true });
    }
    this.timer();
  }

  timer() {
    if (this.timeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    }

    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ visibility: false });
    }, 7000);
  }

  handleClick1 = (evt) => {
    this.setState({ index: 1, visibility: true });
    this.timer();
  }



  handleClick = (evt) => {
    this.setState({ index: 2, visibility: true });
    this.timer()

  }

  handleClick3 = (evt) => {
    this.setState({ index: 3, visibility: true });
    this.timer()
  }

  handleClick4 = (evt) => {
    this.setState({ index: 0, visibility: true })
      ;
    this.timer()
  }

  reload() {
    const iframeLength = this.state.iframeSrcs.length;
    if (this.state.index < iframeLength) {
      this.setState({
        index: this.state.index + 1,
        visibility: true
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ index: 0, visibility: true }); //starting again
    }
    this.timer();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <div>
          {this.state.visibility ? (
            <iframe
              style={{
                position: "absolute",
                left: this.state.leftSrcs[this.state.index],
                right: this.state.rightSrcs[this.state.index],
                top: this.state.topSrcs[this.state.index]
              }}
              key={this.state.index}
              title="AdSlot"
              src={this.state.iframeSrcs[this.state.index]}
              height={this.state.heightSrcs[this.state.index]}
              width={this.state.widthSrcs[this.state.index]}
              scrolling="no"
              frameborder="0"
              allowFullScreen="true"
            />
          ) : (
              ""
            )}
        </div>
        <div>
          <Button variant="outline-info" color="primary" size="lg" style={{ position: "absolute", left: 129 }}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick.bind(this)}>160x600</Button>
          <Button variant="outline-info" color="primary" size="lg" style={{ position: "absolute", left: 509 }}
            onClick={() => this.setState({ index: 3, visibility: true })}>728x90</Button>
          <Button variant="outline-info" color="primary" size="lg" style={{ position: "absolute", left: 888 }}
            onClick={() => this.setState({ index: 2, visibility: true })}>468x60</Button>
          <Button variant="outline-info" color="primary" size="lg" style={{ position: "absolute", left: 1267 }}
            onClick={() => this.setState({ index: 0, visibility: true })}>300x250</Button>

        </div >
      </div >
    );
  }
}
export default PubblicitaPulsanti;
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wrapper method that calls both:

```js
handleClick = (evt) => {
   this.setState({ index: 1, visibility: true });
   this.timer();
}
```

And update your button to have:

```
onClick={this.handleClick}
```

EDIT:

You might be having a race condition where you set visibility to true, but then the timer sets it to false. In that case, you can call the timer **after** the initial state change is complete:

```js
this.setState({ index: 1, visibility: true }, () => {
   // Run timer as a callback here:
   this.timer();
});
```

Comment: I have tried this solution, but it doesn't work. It does not change the state.

Comment: Depending on how your project is setup, you may need to do `this.handleClick.bind(this)` so that `this` is referencing the component.

Comment: I updated the question by entering the complete component code. Even entering "bind (this)" doesn't work. Do you see something wrong?
Thank you so much for the time you are dedicating to me.

Comment: See my edit. Also, there was an extra curly brace on the setState call, so that may also be the issue. Does your console not show any errors?